# Python: error invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, algorithm, compiler-errors, syntax-error

My task is to find how many times we need to multiply digits of a number until only one digit left and count how many "turns" we need to take until that 1 digit left.

Example:

`39 -> 3*9=27 -> 2*7=14 -> 1*4=4`, so the answer should be 3.

[image]

So far I got:

```
def persistence(n):
    
    count = 1
    sum = int(str(n)[0:1]) * int(str(n)[1:2])

    while(n > 0 or sum > 9):

        sum = int(str(sum)[0:1]) * int(str(sum)[1:2])
        count = count + 1
        print(sum)

    print("how many times: " + count) 
    
persistence(39)
```

So how I approached this task:

1. I take first 2 digits convert them to str and multiply them.
2. Already with first sum I go to while loop and keep repeating that.

So, my problem is that I keep getting this:
[image]

How can I solve it? Or should I try to approach this task differently?

Comment: The error says that an empty string is an invalid literal. So think about why you would get an empty string? Maybe you are accessing the "second" digit of a number with less than two digits.

Comment: Did you debug your code? What did you find? For example https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Comment: Yes, very true. It's trying to access non existant digit. Thank you for help and link, very useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have a couple of problems.

1. The `while` loop keeps checking `n`. It only needs to check `sum`
2. The final print tries to add an `int` to a `str`. Just use print arguments instead.

```py
def persistence(n):
    
    count = 1
    sum = int(str(n)[0:1]) * int(str(n)[1:2])

    while sum > 9:

        sum = int(str(sum)[0:1]) * int(str(sum)[1:2])
        count = count + 1
        print(sum)

    print("how many times: ", count) 
    
persistence(39)
```

Output as expected.

However, you should not use `sum` as the name of a variable. You can reuse `n` instead:

```py
def persistence(n):
    
    count = 1
    n = int(str(n)[0:1]) * int(str(n)[1:2])

    while n > 9:

        n = int(str(n)[0:1]) * int(str(n)[1:2])
        count = count + 1
        print(n)

    print("how many times: ", count)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
def returnLength(n):
    return len(str(n))


def returnProduct(n, pro=1):
    n = str(n)
    for i in n:
        pro *= int(i)
    return pro


n = int(input())
c = 0
while returnLength(n) != 1:
    n = returnProduct(n)
    c += 1
print(c)
```

Comment: Interesting solution, all works fine, thank you for your time :)

Comment: btw, I think your `returnLength()` function is redundant in this case. Your `while` loop could be simplified to: `while n > 9:`.

Answer (score 0):

So basically at the start my program had Achilles heel, because it's failed when I had 3+ digit number. I read every suggestion very carefully and my final code went like this:

```
def persistence(n):

    def returnLength(n):
        return len(str(n))
    
    def returnProduct(n, pro=1):
        n = str(n) 
        for i in n:
            pro *= int(i)
        return pro
    
    c = 0

    while n > 9:
        n = returnProduct(n)
        c += 1
    
    print(c)
```

However, I still couldn't pass the test nevertheless everything worked fine on VScode and I did some random manual testing (I'm practicing at codewars.com and a lot of people wrote that on this task's test might have a bug). It might be that I can have only one def. I will try to figure that out. Once again, thank you all.